# Is this question appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I asked the following question:

[Cannot assign address inside a Docker container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037474/cannot-assign-address-inside-a-docker-container)

do you think it would be more appropriate for Stack Overflow, or SuperUser? Or is this the right site?

Comment: Any of those sites is fine, 9 views in a day here is really low but this post will help with that. I would give it another day here and if there is no intrest, move it but make sure you remove it from here if you post it somewhere else, cross posting is not allowed. SO is by far the biggest site, so it would likly get most views there.

Comment: I think this is fine for Super User or Ask Ubuntu, but not Stack Overflow.  The issue you have is a permissions issue, not a Programming issue.

Comment: @ThomasWard ok, I'll leave it here for now. In case it doesn't draw attention, would you suggest that I put a bounty on it, or remove it and post it to Super User?

Comment: @DeltaIV if it doesn't have attention in the next few days, let me know, I"ve got the reputation to spare to put a bounty out there for you.  (Happy to help, where I can).  Up to you though if you decide to remove and repost, though, that's your decision.  Keep in mind that this might ultimately just be a "Docker Containers Are Evil" problem with regards to how binding ports within the container happens - it's possible it doesn't let you do localhost port binds, and you need to bind to 0.0.0.0:port (and then set up Docker to handle the ports handoff to the actual system 'localhost')

Comment: ok thanks. I understood 10% of what you said, but I really appreciate the help and possibly the bounty :-) if this will end up in a  "Docker Containers Are Evil" issue it's ok, at least I'll have learnt something.

Comment: @ThomasWard I was able to solve it. Since my goal was to edit files inside the Docker container, and since I can use `rsub` on the remote host, turns out the simplest thing to do was to edit the files on the host, and to rebuild the container! Rebuilding the container each time 
 edit the files is a bit time consuming, but doable (the remote server has a lot of compute power). Thanks anyway! I'll delete the question

Comment: @DeltaIV better still, explain your solution in an answer

Comment: @Zanna sure, will do

Comment: It looks to have already been answered on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938950/rsub-with-sublime-and-ssh-connection-refusual

Comment: @RobotHumans that question has not been asked in the context of Docker containers, so the solution proposed may not work in my case. I'll check, and if it does, I'll link to it in my answer

Comment: Huh ? Since when Docker and Perl aren't appropriate for Ubuntu ? Keep it here.